# .tex file that had been edited on Mac version of TexStudio and worked just fine doesn't run on Windows 10 TexStudio

Tags: texstudio

I am using both Mac OS and Windows 10 to work on .tex files. On Mac OS it compiles and generates pdf file perfectly.

But when trying to run the same file on Windows 10 in the same environment (TexStudio), I keep seeing the errors: 1) Extra \endgroup. \begin{document}; 2) Missing \begin{document}. \begin{document}

I am definetely having \begin{document} and \end{document} in my code because it RUNS on Mac OS.

How can I run my .tex file on Windows 10?

Comment: you are probably using different class or package versions. Update your windows tex system.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Do you mean documentclass or what? It is the same (because it's the same code). So should I update my TexStudio on both Mac OS and Win10? Sorry for stupid questions, I am a real lamer in Latex

Comment: texstudio is only an editor. You need to update your tex system (texlive or miktex or whatever you are using). Look into your log-file, it will show you that you are using different versions.

Comment: So please add here MWE (a short example of a file that does not compile in your new environment) and we will be able to check the reason(s).

Comment: \documentclass[preprint,aps]{revtex4}
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath,mathtext,enumerate,float}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}


%\nofiles

\begin{document}


\end{document}